# Navigation Bar transparent issue

Tags: html, css, transparent

I've transparent bar which has conflict with `<div id="content">`

When `position:relative;`of `#content` is active the page looks like this:

[image]

When `position:relative;`of `#content` is missing transparent bar is okey

[image]

[http://jsfiddle.net/t0p95q9c/](http://jsfiddle.net/urc_7/t0p95q9c/)

How to make that bar was transparent with relative position of my content?

Comment: Adjust the z-index of div accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need property z-index:1 to #navigation, as LcSalazar says

**and you also need add z-index:2 to .MetroMenuBox, instead of invalid 999px (px is not a valid)**

```
#navigation {
    z-index:1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
}

.MetroMenuBox{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #111111;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t0p95q9c/2/

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a `position` property, the element is affected by the z-index properties.

So, give the navigation a high `z-index` value, that would place it in front of every other positioned elements, like:

```
{
    z-index: 100;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t0p95q9c/1/

Answer (score 0):

check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/t0p95q9c/3/

```
#content {
    z-index: 1;
}
#navigation {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

The idea is to use a bigger integer as the z-index of the layer on top.